# How load html from renderer JS with ELECTRON

Tags: html, electron, load

In develop phase the jquery load method to load html view work well with electron:

```
app.appContainer.load('html/homePage/homePage.html', () => { app.addListenerToHomePage(false) });
```

I have several html file for each page : home, user ... 
I don’t want to open a new window .

Since I make a dist (with electron builder) it doesn't work att all : ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (it try to look to `file:///C:/Users/lexa/AppData/Local/Programs/cleogs/resources/app.asar/html/homePage/homePage.html`)

And I code everything with that load jquery method...

How could I make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue come from electron builder and my configuration probably.
I switch to **forge electron** and it work without change nothing . :D